# How do I make bower install work with aws.push?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bower

As a starting point to making my own app that uses meanjs, I went to the meanjs website and used their yeomen generator to create the template/sample app.  Following the instructions getting the sample application running out of the box on my local desktop machine worked within minutes.  To complete the exercise I tried to deploy the sample app to an AWS/EC2 instance before making any changes to it.  I have used the command line deployment tools in the past and liked it.  Also it is nice how now you can just select an EC2 Linux instance with node and npm already installed and ready.

After checking the sample into git, I run "git aws.push" to deploy the app.

The problem is in the package.json the line:

```
"postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
```

In the eb-activity.log:
***npm WARN cannot run in wd meansample@0.0.1 bower install --config.interactive=false (wd=/tmp/deployment/application)***

The result is that AngularJS ends up not getting installed in /public/lib.

First thing I tried was giving the full path in the package.json file: node_modules/bower/bin/bower.  This didn't help and results in the same error. Also noting that other commands like "grunt" don't need the full path specified in the package.json and they work.

I don't understand enough of the black box magic that aws.push does to understand why this error is happening.  For example what user does it run as?  What permissions does that user have?  what options if any does it use when it runs npm install?

I did figure out a work-around, but it adds a lot of extra steps that shouldn't be required if aws.push was able to run bower install directly.  Basically I can manually run the bower install in the ssh client connected to my EC2 instance, set the owner/group on the installed files, and restart the server.

Work-around steps:

1) On local command prompt run git aws.push.  Wait for unsuccessfully deployment to finish.

2) Connect ssh client to EC2 instance.  From the command prompt:

```
cd /var/app/current
```

/* NOTE:  if I don't use sudo the ec2user I am logged in as does not have permission to create /public/lib needed to install AngularJS into*/

```
sudo node_modules/bower/bin/bower install --config.interactive=false --allow-root
```

/* NOTE: just changing the owner and group to match the same as the other files that aws.push deployed */

```
sudo chown -R nodejs public/lib
sudo chgrp -R nodejs public/lib
```

3. From AWS dashboard, select the correct EC2 instance, Action = Restart App Server(s)

Now AngularJS is install and the sample app works.

How do I eliminate the extra steps and make it so aws.push can do the bower install successfully?

Comment: Using your workaround, I attempted to turn that into something that might work in the post-install script. By thinking was that if I could hijack the same path, running as root, I'd be able to run it inline with the deploy.

So I tried this:
    `"postinstall": "su -s /bin/sh -c PATH=$PATH:$NODE_HOME/bin ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install --config.interactive=false --allow-root"`

but unfortunately, it looks like this stage of the deploy takes place in a temp directory, and it does not allow you to exec in place:

`npm WARN cannot run in wd app@1.0.0 ... (wd=/tmp/deployment/application)`

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem when trying to publish my nodejs app in a private server running CentOs using root user. The same error is fired by "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install" in my package.json file so the only solution that was working for me is to use both options to avoid the error:

1: use --allow-root option for bower install command

```
"postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower --allow-root install"
```

2: use --unsafe-perm option for npm install command

```
npm install --unsafe-perm
```